# javascript namespace issue in socket.io + sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, socket.io

This could be a very basic Javascript I know but I just can't get it..

```
Ext.regController('Chat', {
    initSocketConnection: function() {
    this.chatStore = new App.Store.Chat();
            ...
    this.socket = io.connect(settings.get('server'), {port: 8080});

    this.socket.on(
        'message',
        this.addMessageToChatStore
    );

},

addMessageToChatStore: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
        console.log(this);     << console shows the 'this' has become SocketNameSpace
    this.chatStore.add(message);   << this line error with "Undefined" chatStore

    this.send(message);
},
```

Console print out shows that the `"this"` in the `addMessageToChatStore` function is `"SocketNamespace"`

How to I get rid of the error?

To generalize the problem. I think it's better to describe it as function chain calling dilemma.

A class has some local var that's instance of another class. When this var listens on certain events, it calls the parent's class's method. The problem is when this method is called, it's under the context of the other class and hence the scope has changed and the access to the original parent's class methods are denied.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, the `this` variable is determined by the caller. You could use a self executing function to ensure you're referencing the correct entity rather than using `this`:

```
Ext.regController('Chat', (function() {
  var self = {
    initSocketConnection: function() {
      self.chatStore = new App.Store.Chat();
      ...
      self.socket = io.connect(settings.get('server'), {port: 8080});

      self.socket.on(
        'message',
        this.addMessageToChatStore
      );
    },
    addMessageToChatStore: function(message) {
      console.log(message);
      self.chatStore.add(message);
      self.send(message);
    }
  };
  return self;
}()));
```

**Update**

Based on the full snippet, I'm not sure where the `render` function is defined, if `render` is a global function then `self.viewChat = render({xtype : 'App.View.Chat'});` will suffice, otherwise it may be defined on `this` (the `this` that is defined for the call to `index`) so the following may suffice `self.viewChat = this.render({xtype : 'App.View.Chat'});`.

If I were a betting man, I'd go for the latter, so the code would be (with commented out code removed):

```
Ext.regController('Chat', (function() {
    var self = {
        index: function() {
            if (!self.socket) {
                self.initSocketConnection();
            }

            self.showChat();
        },
        /**
         * init the socket connection to the node.js server
         * using user settings
         *
         */
        initSocketConnection: function() {
            self.chatStore = new App.Store.Chat();
            self.chatStore.add({
                user: "Figo",
                message: "Welcome!"
            });
            self.configStore = Ext.StoreMgr.get('ConfigStore');
            var settings = self.configStore.getAt(0);

            self.socket = io.connect(settings.get('server'), {
                port: 8080
            });

            // Event Listener
            self.socket.on('connect', self.registerUser);
            self.socket.on('message', self.addMessageToChatStore);
            App.on('newMsg', self.sendMessageToServer);
        },
        sendMessageToServer: function(msg) {
            self.socket.send(msg);
        },
        addMessageToChatStore: function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.parent);

            self.chatStore.add(message);
            self.socket.send(message);
        },
        registerUser: function() {
            self.configStore = Ext.StoreMgr.get('ConfigStore');
            var settings = self.configStore.getAt(0);

            var user = {
                nickname: settings.get('nickname'),
                gravatar: settings.get('gravatar')
            };
            console.log(user);
            self.socket.send(user);
        },
        /**
         * Show chat view
         */
        showChat: function() {
            if (!self.viewChat) {

                self.viewChat = this.render({
                    xtype: 'App.View.Chat'
                });

                self.viewChat.query('#settingsButton')[0].on('tap', self.showConfig, self);
            }
            self.application.viewport.setActiveItem(
            self.viewChat, {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left'
            });
        },
        /**
         * Show config View
         */
        showConfig: function() {
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: 'Viewport',
                action: 'showConfig'
            });
        }
    };
    return self;
}()));
```

Comment: I tried but it complains: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier " right over the var={ line

Comment: @Figo the `...` bit should be removed. Otherwise the code is perfectly valid according to jsLint.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have some other functions within the self that reference some global methods I think which use this..

Comment: Is there any other way besides self function to solve this? I'm coming from a C/C++ background. The implicit of 'this' when calling a function chain is driving me crazy

Comment: @Figo a self executing function is just a simple way of scoping entities within the correct context. The `this` in javascript is a little different to what most people expect, you'll get used to it eventually! If you want to post the entire code I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Ok. I just pasted the whole block of code above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rich, neither of them works for me..it's the same error. any other tricks?

Comment: @Figo Unfortunately not, I don't know where the render method is defined (or if it even exists - I can't find any reference to a suitable looking render method from sencha touch docs.). It's probably best to post this problem as a separate question. Hopefully I've provided a solution to the original question regarding scoping. Good luck solving it!

Answer (score 0):

For @Rich.okelly

Here's the error (highlighted in code)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'render' app.all.js:438
self.showChat app.all.js:438
self.index app.all.js:351
Ext.util.Dispatcher.Ext.extend.dispatch sencha-touch-debug.js:10630
Ext.dispatch sencha-touch-debug.js:10667
Ext.regController.showChat app.all.js:293
fire sencha-touch-debug.js:979
Ext.util.Observable.Ext.extend.fireEvent sencha-touch-debug.js:595
```

And here's the full code (other code within the same project not shown):

```
Ext.regController('Chat',(function() {
    var self = {
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    index: function() {

        if (!self.socket) {
            self.initSocketConnection();
        }

        self.showChat();
    },

    /**
     * init the socket connection to the node.js server
     * using user settings
     *
     */
    initSocketConnection: function() {
        self.chatStore = new App.Store.Chat();
        self.chatStore.add({user: "Figo", message: "Welcome!"});
        self.configStore = Ext.StoreMgr.get('ConfigStore');
        //this.configStore = new App.Store.Config()
        var settings = self.configStore.getAt(0);

        //this.socket = new App.util.Socketio(settings.get('server'), {port: 4000});
        //this.socket.connect();
        self.socket = io.connect(settings.get('server'), {port: 8080});

        /*
        this.socket.on('message', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                this.parent.addMessageToChatStore(data);
                this.emit('message', data);
        });

        this.socket.on('message', 
                this.addMessageToChatStore
        );
         */     

        // Event Listener

        self.socket.on(
            'connect',
            self.registerUser
        );


        self.socket.on(
            'message',
            self.addMessageToChatStore
        );


        App.on(
            'newMsg',
            self.sendMessageToServer
        ); 
    },

    sendMessageToServer: function(msg){
        self.socket.send(msg);
    },


    addMessageToChatStore: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
                  console.log(this);
                  console.log(this.parent);
        //if (!this.chatStore)
        //this.chatStore = new App.Store.Chat();
        self.chatStore.add(message);
        //App.Controller.Chat.chatStore.add(message);

        self.socket.send(message);
    },


    registerUser: function() {
        self.configStore = Ext.StoreMgr.get('ConfigStore');
        var settings = self.configStore.getAt(0);

        var user = {
            nickname: settings.get('nickname'),
            gravatar: settings.get('gravatar')
        };
        console.log(user);
        self.socket.send(user);
    },

    /**
     * Show chat view
     */
    showChat: function() {
        if (!self.viewChat) {

            self.viewChat = self.render({    << fails over here
                xtype: 'App.View.Chat'
            });

            self.viewChat.query('#settingsButton')[0].on(
                'tap',
                self.showConfig,
                self
            );
        }
        self.application.viewport.setActiveItem(
            self.viewChat,
            {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left'
            }
        );
    },

    /**
     * Show config View
     */
    showConfig: function() {
        Ext.dispatch({
            controller: 'Viewport',
            action    : 'showConfig'
        });
    }

    };
    return self;
}()));
```